# I want to split array of string in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a data extension field called (Status) that stores an array of strings, in the salesforce marketing cloud which I want to split as below with

Original Table

| email | Status |
| --- | --- |
| kie@gmail.com | c121,c122 |
| vk@gmail.com | c121,h120 |

Desired Table

```
| email | Status |
| -------- |---------|
| kie@gmail.com|c121|
| kie@gmail.com|c122|
| vk@gmail.com|c121|
| vk@gmail.com|h120|
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384602/edit) your question to add what you have tried (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, this retrieves the output as expected above......

Please refer this great article by [Adam-spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) **[Parsing Delimited Fields Values with SQL Cross Apply](https://sprignaturemoves.com/parsing-delimited-fields-values-with-sql-cross-apply/)**

```sql
SELECT a.email,
       Substring(a.status, 1, Isnull(p1 - 1, Len(a.status))) AS [status]
FROM   [poc_split_based_on_comma] a
       CROSS apply (SELECT NULLIF(Charindex(',', a.status), 0)) b(p1)
       CROSS apply (SELECT NULLIF(Charindex(',', a.status, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
UNION
SELECT a.email,
       Substring(a.status, p1 + 1, Isnull(p2, Len(a.status) + 1) - p1 - 1) AS
       [status2]
FROM   [poc_split_based_on_comma] a
       CROSS apply (SELECT NULLIF(Charindex(',', a.status), 0)) b(p1)
       CROSS apply (SELECT NULLIF(Charindex(',', a.status, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
```

> This is just a POC SQL, works for only 2 comma separated values, make necessary changes and DO *please validate* before implementing in production

Comment: Thanks, Vishal, it did work not as expected but with some tricks it should work. I know primary keys are unique but in this case, I want them to appear as duplicates due to the string values.

Comment: can u try Composite keys..... I mean make BOTH fields as Primary keys!